# want to add a function to angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to add a function to this angular-ui datepicker directive https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepickerPopup to hide the back and forth arrows so that the user cannot go past a year's date from now. I have no idea where to start. I think a decorator would be the solution to my problem but I don't know how to start the tutorials didn't help me any suggestions where to start would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the `Datepicker` directive from Angular-UI. The `date-disabled` attribute lets you disable certain dates (weekends for example). See this plunk
[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGAU0L?p=preview)

If you want to dynamically disable dates based on selection, you can use the min and max attributes and watchers. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W5pb1boMLOHZFnWkMU8o?p=preview)

Comment: I have them disabled already but that doesn't hide the navigation arrow I want to hide it

Comment: For that you can find `btn pull-left` class and add css to that as `display:none` in directive.

Comment: that will hide it for all months I only want to hide it for the months after one year

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question in case this helps anyone I ended up using the mixin pattern as described here: http://moduscreate.com/angularjs-tricks-with-angular-extend/

and the sample code 
angular
    .module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker')
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

```
angular.extend($scope, angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker').controller('DatepickerController').$scope);
angular.extend($scope, {
    hideYearNav: function(){
        // the function body goes in here
    }
});
```

});